# separate json content that separated by a comma

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I am parsing json data in swift 3. this is the structure of the result.
I need to separate this brackected content and put them into a array.

```
 (
    { 
        name:"devin,patrick";
    }
       ,

   {
        name:"devin,kalvin";
   }
      ,

   {
       name: "devin,nic";
   }

)
```

This is the code,

```
 //parsing json data

                if let jsonparsed = content as? NSDictionary {

                    if let neededData = jsonparsed["data"] {

                        print(neededData)

                        let exactData = String(describing:neededData)
                 let gotData = exactData.components(separatedBy: ",")



                    }
                }
```

I converted data to a string and tried to separate content by comma, it wont work because name also having commas, I need to separate content that covered by comma, Any help would be great.

Comment: So you have already parsed the JSON, you just need to separate the values inside the `name` String?

Comment: yes, I need to separate content that include name string, I am trying to create and array and genarate tableview. I cant think how to separate this content.

Comment: Don't ever modify/parse the JSON *string*, this is not how it works. Instead, properly convert the JSON to its counterpart objects using JSONSerialization.

Comment: Please include your actual JSON response before doing any parsing on it, just the `jsonObject` that you get using `JSONSerialization.jsonObject`. Also don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use its native Swift counterpart, Dictionary. Also don't parse any data into `String` using `String(describing:...)`, since it just does the same as `object.description` if the object conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`, which is not what you usually need and is definitely what you need for parsing JSON.

Comment: this is the url I'm using:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/juvmwf45zmn1kqt/hetels.json

Comment: thank you very much for your help..

Answer (score 1):

After serializing your json string, get a list of Dictionary, get the name of each dictionary and then do the componentsSeparatedBy yo get every name

```
   if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) ,
        let dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: String]{

        let array = dict.flatMap({$0["name"]}) //return ["devin,patrick", "devin,kalvin", "devin,nic"]
        let names = array.flatMap({$0.components(separatedBy: ",")}) //return ["devin" ,"patrick" ,"devin" ,"kalvin" ,"devin" ,"nic"]
        let uniqueNames = Set(names) // return ["nic", "patrick", "devin", "kalvin"]
    }
```

Comment: Yes but: `You need to serialize your json string` Actually OP already has the JSON data, since they show us a printed object. No need to do Data -> String -> Data, they should just use the original data...

Comment: @Moritz True but the question of Olivier changed while I was writing the answer, there were no code in his first post ;)

Comment: Yeah I know, and your answer is good. I just felt the need to remind the reader about this fact. :)